# Workflow editing for non-developers

Tags: .net, workflow

At this time, I have to design a solution for a multi-level approval workflow in a .net System. But the requirement of the customer is: they want to modify the workflow by themselves with a bit knowledge of Visio, and not anything with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a long, hard look at SharePoint 2010. There are some third-party vendors that sell components if needed.

**EDIT:** [This](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexWorkflow2010.aspx) is one product I've heard of but have not used. It's supposed to make it easier for non-programmers to create SharePoint workflows.

Some BPM vendors offer Visio conversion options; these systems tend to be expensive and are likely to require significant time and resources just to get them installed.